# Implementing VR UI/Menu? (Tried tutorials but none help)

Tags: user-interface, menu, virtual-reality, oculus, 360-virtual-reality

I want to make an app with several different 360 videos and the problem I have is creating a Menu/UI for selecting which 360 video to play for the Oculus Go.

I tried the Getting Started with 360 Video tutorial for Unity VR but found that it had corrupt prefabs and couldn't get through the tutorial. I also tried VRTK but couldn't get that working either after following the setup tutorial to the teeth. I must have spent at least 15h on searching for a solution now.

For the Getting Started With 360 Video tutorial, when I try to drag any of the prefabs into the scene or the hierarchy, it doesn't instantiate. Either I'm not understanding something (which is certainly possible) or the file is broken (which I think it is since the scenes have these corrupt empty prefabs). I've tried this in a few different versions of Unity but kept getting the same issue as well. If you happen to have these files available, would you be so kind to share them?

The below is the tutorial I was referring to and the assets it came:
Tutorial Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf2Jb6tk1GY&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0TifrTlupfrJeLa7c8LunUf&index=3
Assets Link: https://ole.unity.com/get360video

There's no code since it's all in Unity.

For the 360 video the error is that some of the prefabs don't instantiate. And the scenes have broken prefabs. And the VRTK video tutorials lead to errors when I try to build it to test on Oculus Go. It just says there is an error in building and it was due to Gradle. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9mub3CvTvQ) and (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psPVNddjgGw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, totally independent from you creating a 360 Video Player, your problem is to create UI Elements and interact with them on an Oculus Go, correct?

I do it the way it's described by Oculus:
[Oculus Unity UI Guide](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/)

If you want to make use of the controller, you just set the gaze transforms to a hand instead of your center eye and et voila, you have a pointer to click on Unity UI Elements. If you get stuck in the process, let me know.

Best,
Adrian